# how to convert maven pom.xml into build.gradle file?

Tags: xml, maven, gradle

I have a maven pom.xml file I need to convert into a build.gradle file. How do I do this? For example, I am defining a resources file in the pom.xml file:

```
 <resources>
  <resource>
   <directory>src/main/resources/</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>config.properties</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
   </resources>
```

Comment: did you check https://guides.gradle.org/migrating-from-maven/ ?

Comment: Cool! Thank you for the link! I will try it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `gradle init` in a directory with `pom.xml` it will try to convert some configuration parts automagically for you. Though it's not complete but you'll get the most basic parts converted: multi-module setup, repositories and dependencies.

Generally, `src/main/resources` is already recognized as "resources" directory by both Maven and Gradle, so you don't need to configure it separately unless the config is not standard. E.g. you can enable filtering by:

```
<resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
</resource>
```

In Gradle you'll need to configure `processResources` (`processMainResources`) task:

```
processResources {
    expand project.properties
}
```

However, it's not the only way and you may find [`filter`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/AbstractCopyTask.html#filter-java.lang.Class-) more useful.